# Phonegap white blank screen shown for 1-2 seconds when redirecting from one page to another page locally

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi I am working on simple phonegap application in which user make login at the first page and after that if login is successful then user is redirected to another page which is used to show news feed from the web server 
my problem is that when user is redirected from login to news page a white screen is shown for 1-2 seconds and after which the news page is shown ,

i did some research and find out that the screen is shown by android by default because the news page is not loaded(ready) in the device and once the page is loaded the white screen is replaced by the actual page 
i am using phonegap latest version-3
please help me to find a solution i don't want to show the empty white screen

List of various link from where i am getting data

```
var xmlFeed = [
           {
           "News":[
                   {name: 'News', url : 'http://test1.php', visible: true}

                   ],
           "Rockstar":[
                   {name: 'Rockstar', url : 'http://test1.php', visible: true}

                   ],
           "CaseStudy":[
                         {name: 'Art&Culture', url : 'http://test2.php', visible: true}
                               ],

           }];
```

and code to fetch and show the data in device

```
function getNewsFeed(i, field) {

var $homePage = $('#home-page');
$homePage.find("#list_main").empty();

if (isCategoryVisible(field.name)) {

    $
            .ajax({
                url : field.url,
                dataType : 'xml',
                type : 'GET',
                beforeSend : function() {
                    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
                },
                complete : function() {
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                    if(firsttime)
                    {
                        firsttime=false;
                        $("#custom_loader").remove();
                        document.getElementById('wrapper').style.top = "126px";
                        //document.getElementById('wrapper').style.margin-top = "150px";
                    }
                },
                success : function(data) {

                    // console.log(data);
                    dataPool = data;
                    // alert(dataPool);

                    if ($(data).find("item").length > 0) {

                        $(data)
                                .find("item")
                                .each(
                                        function(i, val) {

                                            var main_list = 'main_list' + i;
                                            var a_list = 'a_list' + i;
                                            total_article=i;
                                            $homePage
                                                    .find("#list_main")
                                                    .append(
                                                            '<li id="'
                                                                    + main_list
                                                                    + '" data-name="'
                                                                    + main_list
                                                                    + '" data-icon="false" class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="#" id="'+ a_list+'"><img class="list_img" src="images/default.png" /><h2 class="wrap_text" style="white-space: normal !important;">Fever Sales Tool</h2><p>By:Marketing Team</p></a></li>');


                                            $("#list_main").listview(
                                                    "refresh");
                                            var nTitle = $(this).find(
                                                    "title").text();
                                            var nLink = $(this).find(
                                                    "img_url").text();

                                            $homePage.find("#" + main_list)
                                                    .find("h2").text(nTitle);
                                            if(nLink.length>0){
                                            $homePage.find("#" + main_list)
                                                    .find("img").attr(
                                                            "src", nLink);

                                            $(".wrap_text").css('width', wrap_text);//wrap the text
                                            }

                                        });
                    }

                    $.mobile.loading('hide');
                    // myScroll.refresh();
                    // return;
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // console.log("Error status :"+textStatus);
                    // alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);
                    // alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);
                }
            });
}
```

}

Thanks...

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Hi Siddharth -i have included the code in edited question please check

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything you can do about it. Page will obviously take some time to load from server. I can think of a way around. Using the `inAppBrowser` plugin you can load the server page first and make the `inAppbrowser`view visible after loading complete. In the mean time you can show anything in your page, perhaps a loading sign.

Comment: -my problem is not with the loading of data from the webserver when data is getting loaded i am showing a loading sign and it is working fine,i am facing the issue with the delay in loading of files in the android device ,device ready event is getting fired after 1 or 2 seconds after the user is redirected from the login page and in that duration white page is displayed